# Can someone explain why this post is not spam?

Tags: support, specific-question, declined-flags, spam

Can anyone explain why this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66349516/get-json-from-shopee-api-always-returns-different-result) is not SPAM?

The question contains a link to a product and it is added simply for the link building.

Also, the question is unclear and does not provide a minimal explanation.

If it is a good question then a link to the JSON API is more than enough.

Here is the screenshot of question:

> [image: question screenshot]

I am asking this to understand more and to make my next review even better.

Comment: There is nothing spammy about that link. It doesn't seem to be related to the OP in any way. They are genuinely asking how to scrape a website and posting the link to the page they are scraping...

Comment: The fact the author linked to the product, doesn’t make that spam, as they linked to images of the product.  It’s just a poorly formatted and worded question.  I see no reason to raise a spam flag.  Making keywords a link is the reason it was fishy but when the keywords are to an image to an uploaded image it’s not spam.

Comment: @SecurityHound, It's not about the uploaded images. The link in the post to a product looked suspicious to me. I was confused. Now it's clearly for me.

Comment: I agree the hot linking of those specific words was weird, but further investigation, indicated they were to images hosted by Imgur (I.e image upload)

Comment: it is not spam, because it links only to iunformation, but simply downvote it

Comment: @NKSM he wants to grab data from a certain website and ask about how to do it. This is not spam as he doesn't want you to by what ever the link leads to, only to give you a sample of data he wanst to grab, that os not spam as it doesn't promite the shoes or whatever

Comment: @nbk, I will not argue with you what the question is about. It’s not so important now. Now it is already clear to me that if in doubt, then i need to raise a custom mod flag. Thanks)))

Comment: @NKSM - or, better yet, edit it out if you feel it is irrelevant and forget about it. Usually (at least as far as my limited experience goes - I rarely encounter spam), truly malicious users have a history of several posts that look like legitimate questions/answers on the surface. The rest are either obvious spam posts (i.e., advertisement dumps) or legit posts like the one in question, where the user tried to highlight a mismatch between an API response and the actual product page (not sure why they called their task a "scrape" if they are using an API, but I digress)

Comment: @OlegValter, Thanks for the tips, I will take this into account in my next reviews.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I rejected the second flag you cast. The post is **not spam** as it is not astroturfing that website.

There are, so far [7 questions about scraping that site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=url%3Ashopee.sg), all from different people with no correlation between the posts or the accounts, and the [site wasn't seen as spam before](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body_is_regex=1&body=%5Cbshopee%5C.sg%5Cb).

It is quite common for people that are struggling with a task to scrape a specific site, to ask a question about that on Stack Overflow with the link of the page they are trying to scrape included. And that's exactly what this post includes here: the URL they are trying to scrape, and a description of what data they wanted to get from that page.

Nowhere is the question giving you the impression that following the link is going to be a great idea, that you'll find the solution to all your problems there, or the cheapest, bestest ever product. It therefore fails [our definition of spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor):

> A post should be marked as spam only if it **promotes** a product, service, or similar; ***and* is unsolicited *or* lacks disclosure of affiliation.**

The post doesn't promote *anything*.

Do not flag questions as spam just because they are unclear and contain a link to a commercial site. This question is just off topic, but the account doesn't need to be subjected to our usual anti-spam measures.

Comment: Your answer with facts sounds more than convincing. Thank you for your detailed answer and explanation. In my further reviews, I will take into account your notes.

Answer (score 21):

Because it doesn't really look like they are promoting the website. The link is just an example of the website they want to scrape.

Bad question? Sure. Spam? Not certain.

And without further evidence, not really worth a spam flag.

Or maybe it's a very poor attempt at selling us latex gloves. But in any case, it's unlikely enough. Just having a link doesn't make a post spam. Not even if the link points to a product page.

Comment: But this link is nothing to do with question. Not really related.

Comment: @NKSM What do you mean it has nothing to do with the question? *"I am trying to scrape and save data from shopee"*

Comment: Yeah, I mean. If you disregard that they want to scrape information about that shop, and about that specific product... is completely unrelated.

Comment: @NKSM I assume you raised a spam flag and was declined. The decline message didn't include any text?

Comment: @yivi, Yes there is, but it was not entirely clear to me: "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Comment: @yivi, Now it's more clearly for me. I'll be more careful in the future before marking post as spam. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @NKSM - btw, note that "spam" is a very serious accusation on SO, so please don't just be more careful, use the flag *only* if you are sure the post exists *solely* to promote something. Also, if it is not immediately obvious from the post, and you are dead sure ot is spam, raise a custom mod flag providing details of the investigation.

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Hot does this link related to the question? He fetches data from XML FEED link,  not from product link.

Comment: @NKSM There are four links in total. The first is a direct link to the site in question. The second one is the GET response. The last two are simply images of the page and the GET requests. Again, what here is not related to the question?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, the link to product (first link). How can this link help answer his question?

Comment: @NKSM give context? Allow to test it yourself? As described above by Oleg, if there are no ***clear*** indications of spam, raise a custom mod flag describing your reasons for suspicion

Comment: @NKSM: The first link shows the data they *expect* to get, as highlighted in the screenshot. Without that link, the obvious question would be "why are you expecting to get a value of 615? How did you get that number to start with?"

Comment: @JonSkeet, He fetches data from **XML FEED** not from product page details. If you look at the second uploaded image, you will see the request url and the grabbed field ("[shopee.sg/api](https://shopee.sg/api/v2/item/get?itemid=3775568979&shopid=270004860)", "historical_sold"). OK, with Martijn's answer, it's clear to me now. Thanks

Comment: @NKSM: Yes, he fetches data from the JSON API (not XML in fact - I don't see any XML there) *and wants to get the same number that's on the product page*. From the question: "Returned data should be 615 for Sold as on the website" - note the "as on the website" part. To me, that makes "what's on the website" very, very relevant to the question. (And the question really seems pretty clear to me.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, OK, JSON API and product details are different pages. And you can't compare them. You can't guess how it is generated on the server.

Comment: @NKSM: But if the JSON API (again, *still* no XML there) is meant to give you data about the product, and that includes sales (the "historical sold" property), then it seems reasonable to expect that data to be the same as on the product page. It seems like an *entirely* reasonable question, essentially: "I want to programmatically get the same data that's displayed *here*, using *this* API which looks like it should give me that data, but the data is different." That's not spam, it's not unclear, and it's entirely reasonable IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thank you, I already understood that this is't spam and why not spam.