# A scrollbar appears when hovering over the "New contributor" indicator

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, new-contributor-indicator

I was just checking the Meta questions to see if I could answer any when I noticed a strange bug on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405541/can-someone-explain-why-this-post-is-not-spam). After doing more investigation, it seems that this happens with any questions posted by a new user on both Meta and Stack Overflow, regardless of how long the question is.

When I hover my mouse over the "New contributor" indicator, a little scrollbar appears on the side:

[image: Hovering over the "New contributor" indicator]

And then I am actually able to scroll downwards by using 2 fingers on my keypad or my touchscreen (i.e. scrolling without moving my mouse to the scrollbar):

[image: Scrolled to show the whole tooltip]

When I move my mouse off the "New contributor" indicator, this effect disappears. Is this reproducible by you guys, and if so is this intended behavior or a bug?

Sidenote: I definitely remember that previously, that little "New contributor" notification would show on top of the other elements. So there must've been some update recently that caused this new bug.

Comment: Repro-ed on Chrome / Win10, on  MSE so it is not just MSO.

Comment: Yep, seems to affect all sites. Reproduced on Firefox and Chrome (Windows) on the main site.

Comment: def a bug, considering it's caused by a popup that's being hidden below the fold of that element rather than showing over the below content

Comment: This is introduced by [a change to help with MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350687/stack-exchange-sites-with-mathjax-incorrectly-crop-the-zoomed-version-of-latex), I'm investigating now, thanks!

Comment: Whoop, didn't think to check here before I [posted a bug report over on the global Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361444/622284). Apologies for posting a cross-site dupe.

Comment: Hmm, I actually kinda think it's satisfying, but I don't mind if it is fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The change that introduced this bug has been reverted.

Comment: [The change in question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/361439/377214)